# Python New Thread Causes Previous Threads to not work

Tags: python, multithreading

I had a projects with 6 threads running in parallel to fill an sqlite database. Now I wanted to add a new thread to fill a new table I added to the database.

The threads itself worked fine, but it 'canceled' some of the other threads. If I don't use the `timetable_thread.start()`command, then the others work fine. The moment I activate this line, other threads stop actually updating the database.

Here's the code itself, with everything relating to the threads:

```
global updateValue
global threadsValue
global agencies_thread
global companies_thread
global contracts_thread
global orders_thread
global projects_thread
global resources_thread
global timetable_thread
if threadsValue == 1:
       agencies_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_agencies, name="Database Updater")
       companies_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_companies, name="Database Updater")
       contracts_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_contracts, name="Database Updater")
       orders_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_orders, name="Database Updater")
       projects_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_projects, name="Database Updater")
       resources_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_resources, name="Database Updater")
       timetable_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_time, name='Database Updater')
       threadsValue = 0
       if updateValue == 0:
                timetable_thread.start()
                agencies_thread.start()
                companies_thread.start()
                contracts_thread.start()
                orders_thread.start()
                projects_thread.start()
                resources_thread.start()
                updateValue = 1
            updateState = 0
        if agencies_thread.is_alive():
                agenciesState = 'en cours de chargement'
        else:
                agenciesState = 'Chargement terminé'
                updateState += 1
        if companies_thread.is_alive():
                companiesState = 'en cours de chargement'
        else:
                companiesState = 'Chargement terminé'
                updateState += 1
        if contracts_thread.is_alive():
                contractsState = 'en cours de chargement'
        else:
                contractsState = 'Chargement terminé'
                updateState += 1
        if orders_thread.is_alive():
                ordersState = 'en cours de chargement'
        else:
                ordersState = 'Chargement terminé'
                updateState += 1
        if projects_thread.is_alive():
                projectsState = 'en cours de chargement'
        else:
                projectsState = 'Chargement terminé'
                updateState += 1
        if resources_thread.is_alive():
                resourcesState = 'en cours de chargement'
        else:
                resourcesState = 'Chargement terminé'
                updateState += 1
        if timetable_thread.is_alive():
                timeState = 'en cours de chargement'
        else:
                timeState = 'Chargement terminé'
                updateState += 1
        if updateState == 7:
                updateValue = 0
                threadsValue = 1
                copy_db()
                context['updateState'] = 'Base de données mise à jour.'
                html_template = loader.get_template('index.html')
                return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
        else:
                context['agenciesState'] = agenciesState
                context['companiesState'] = companiesState
                context['contractsState'] = contractsState
                context['ordersState'] = ordersState
                context['projectsState'] = projectsState
                context['resourcesState'] = resourcesState
                context['timeState'] = timeState
                html_template = loader.get_template('loading.html')
                return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

Basically, what I get is:
The `if x_thread.is_alive()` becomes false without actually having run the associated function. (x=contracts,projects,orders)

Here is the code for my `fill_time` function:

```
def fill_time():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/app/docaret.sqlite3')
    c = conn.cursor()

    r = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+'/api/resources?&maxResults=500',auth=(USER,PASS))
    data0 = json.loads(r.text)

    for res in data0['data']:
        if res['attributes']['state'] == 1:
            internal = 0
            production = ''
            absence = 0
            projList = []
            idList= []
            r1 = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+'/api/resources/'+res['id']+'/times-reports?&maxResults=500',auth=(USER,PASS))
            data1 = json.loads(r1.text)
            for sheet in data1['data']:
                today = str(datetime.today()).split(' ')[0]
                if sheet['attributes']['term'].split('-')[0]==today.split('-')[0] and sheet['attributes']['term'].split('-')[1]==str(int(today.split('-')[1])-1).zfill(2):
                    r2 = pip._vendor.requests.get(BASE_URL+'/api/times-reports/'+sheet['id']+'?&maxResults=500',auth=(USER,PASS))
                    data2 = json.loads(r2.text)
                    for day in data2['data']['attributes']['regularTimes']:
                        if day['workUnitType']['activityType'] == 'internal':
                            internal += day['duration']
                        elif day['workUnitType']['activityType'] == 'absence':
                            absence += day['duration']
                        elif day['workUnitType']['activityType'] == 'production':
                            if day['project']['id'] not in idList:
                                projList += [[day['project']['id'], day['duration']]]
                                idList.append(day['project']['id'])
                            else :
                                for k in projList:
                                    if k[0] == day['project']['id']:
                                        k[1] += 1
                    for k in projList:   
                        newtext = str(k[0])+'&'+str(k[1])+'$$'
                        production += newtext
                    values = [res['id'],res['id'],sheet['attributes']['term'],encrypt(production),encrypt(str(internal)),encrypt(str(absence))]
                c.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TIME (id,resource,month,production,internal,absence) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);',values)                         
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Without running the thread associated with this function, the other threads work fine and I can see the database updates. When this thread runs, threads that would take longer than it just don't update or stop halfway (it seems).

**Edits**:

- Some grammar and spelling
- Precision on `x_thread`
- `fill_time` function code

Comment: Can't see `if x_thread.is_alive()` in your code; which line do you mean?

Comment: the x represents any of the following threads (contracts, orders, projects).

Comment: Thread(s) could have finished before you get the `y_thread.is_alive()` test - have you done any debugging on the thread functions, e.g. make them print something when they exit? I'm guessing your problem is due to code not in your question.

Comment: I checked to see if my database was updated following this. It was not. And without ```timetable_thread``` running, they do work fine and update the data. I can add the code for the ```fill_time function``` if you want to take a look.

Comment: Given it's literally not possible to 'cancel' a thread, it must be your program logic; the thread must have exited. Look at the conditions under which the thread could have exited, casting aside all assumptions about how it used to work, or might work, or should work, or how you want it to work: look for how it actually works when the timetable thread also runs.

Comment: I tried running ```timetable_thread``` after the other threads had finished and this worked.

Comment: OK, so what does timetable_thread do that might (in)conceivably help one of your other threads to exit before you want it to? Is there an exception you're not catching? or some other logic that could make it exit? If you've got `try:...except:pass` anywhere in your code, make the except log something so you know if you're suppressing errors. Anyway, make your thread functions log what they do and when they exit so you start to get an indication of what's going on.